# Does synchronous execution of async operations block CPU

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

When a thread synchronously executes an async method that could have been awaited (e.g. a long-lasting network operation), the thread cannot be re-used, but will this thread also waste CPU resources by running idly? Or will .NET / the operating system know that a thread is currently actively waiting and won't even allocate it to the CPU?

```
string result = DownloadStringAsync().Result // will I be wasting CPU resources as well or just blocking the current thread?
```

This goes without saying, but don't write code like this.

Comment: "Running idly" is an oxymoron. If a thread is idle, it isn't running. That code will block a thread, but that thread won't be consuming CPU time

Answer (score 7):

No. Blocking does not waste CPU time, at least not in significant amounts. It *does* "waste" some memory, since each thread has some memory, and the thread cannot be used for anything else while blocked.

Blocking a thread marks the thread as not ready for execution, and the scheduler will schedule some other thread for execution until the blocked thread is unblocked.

There is the concept of "spinlock", that is essentially just a loop checking some shared variable. This *does* waste CPU time, but results in lower latency, since the thread does not lose its time slot. This may also result in problems if the thread that hold the lock cannot be scheduled to run due to the CPU being monopolized by the waiting thread.

Synchronization that use a `Monitor`, like `lock`, uses a hybrid scheme, where it will first a spinlock for some number of cycles, and if the monitor does not become available for this time it will pause the thread. I'm not sure if `.Result` uses a monitor or some other synchronization mechanism, but you should probably not worry about it in either case.

If you write a UI program you should worry about deadlocks. Since using `.Result` on the UI thread with task that needs the UI thread to complete will cause a deadlock. And It is not always apparent if a task require the UI thread to complete or not.

Another potential problem to be concerned about is thread pool exhaustion, where all or most threads are blocked, so tasks that is available to run cannot get a thread to run on. The threadpool will create new threads to avoid a complete lock-up, but this is intentionally slow.

Answer (score 5):

> When a thread synchronously executes an async method...

Allow me to correct your terminology. Asynchronous methods typically [don't run on threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). For the most part they use hardware other than the CPU, like network cards or disk drivers, where the concept of "thread" does not apply. When you wait a `Task`, using either `.Wait()`, `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, you instruct the current thread to be blocked until the task completes. The blocking of the thread doesn't assist the asynchronous operation in any way. It's an event parasitic to the asynchronous operation, that you decided to attach for your own reasons. What happens internally ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ebe11caae43041522d990bf9a5c0b00cc909f72d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L3039)) is that a [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) is instantiated, it is hooked for a signal on the continuation of the task, and its method `Wait` is called. The [`ManualResetEventSlim.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.wait) method blocks the current thread until the component is [`Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.set) by another thread. A blocked thread [doesn't consume CPU resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481845/does-blocked-thread-incur-performance-penalty).

[image: Workers and slackers]

Comment: _A blocked thread doesn't consume CPU resources_ - only if blocking caused by blocking-primitive. Spin-based primitives consume resources. Though ManualResetEventSlim uses hybrid approach, afaik.

Comment: @Ryan sure, some primitives do a bit of spinning before putting the thread to sleep, but the duration of the spinning is so small (in the order of nanoseconds) to be practically negligible. I don't think that the OP is worried about that.